# AngularJS ---- Variable not binding as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding

```js
$scope.addGridRow = function (grid) {
      console.log(grid);
      $scope[grid].addRow();
    };
```

```html
<a
            href="#"
            ng-if="action !== 'get'"
            class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
            ng-click="addGridRow('{{p.typeNo}}Grid')"
            ng-attr-title="{{ 'common.add' | translate }}"
          >
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>{{ 'common.add' | translate }}
          </a>
```

I am trying to use AngularJS binding to make a dynamic ng-click function, so each type of grid can have its corresponding addGridRow function,
for example, if the p.typeNo is 1, then its parameter would be "1Grid", which would be passed into the addGridRow function, and then $scope["1Grid"].addRow() would be called inside the addGridRow function.

However, the binding seems not working, i have logged the grid parameter, it shows its original outlook, but the binding works well in the html, i m confused how to fix it.

[image: ScrShot of the html element]

[image: ScrShot of the error in console]

Comment: I don't know the rest of your code but could you please try this to see if it works addGridRow(p.typeNo)

Comment: @AlexsanderGutierreez Omg, it works, but why? what happened? So we can't use {{}} binding in the parameter?

Comment: Because the variable has already been defined and is accessible in component scope. I believe you defined it in some *ngFor in your template code?

Comment: @AlexsanderGutierreez u means the p variable? yes, I have defined it in ng-repeat.  BTW, do you know if we can announce a $scope attribute like this: $scope['newAttribute"] ？Thanks a lot.